# Facebook-omniauth & associations: how to associate friends with a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, omniauth, model-associations

I'm using the Facebook-Omniauth gem to connect people to my app. I can see when a new user logs in, it creates a new user record in my database. My app is supposed to connect users to their friends and their events...but it simply connects users to *all* friends(people) and all events in the database.

In User.rb:

```
  has_many :people
  has_many :people, 
    :through => :friends
```

In Person.rb:

```
has_many :users, 
    :through => :friends
```

In Friend.rb:

```
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :users
```

After authenticating via Omniauth I loop through all the friends a user has and try to add them as the user's friend like so:

```
self.people << @new_person
```

But ActiveRecord yells back the following:

```
[3] pry(#<User>)> self.people << @new_person
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :friends in model User

[4] pry(#<User>)> self.friends << @new_person
NoMethodError: undefined method `friends' for #<User:0x007f9b816850f0>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
 has_many :friends
```

In your models?